# How to have data shared between Vue3 single file component instances?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, multiple-instances

I don't need to pass data between a parent component to a child one or the opposite, I need something like php/c static variables.

I want my sfc (single file component) to have some data that is shared among all instances in in the page.

As far as I understand that's why in sfc we define `data` as a function

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            // props here
        };
    }
}
```

while in page scripts we can define it as an object

```js
const app = new Vue({
    data: {
        // props here
    },
}
```

That's because since we can have multiple instances of a sfc in the page defining its data as a function make each instance to execute in and get its own `data`, while with page script we can have a singe instance.

I need to define some of my sfc data to be shared between component instances, while other data to be per-instance.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the data to be defined, its complexity, and purpose.

If these are 2 or 3 readonly variables, they can be set as global properties using `Vue.prototype` (Vue 2) or `app.config.globalProperties` (Vue 3). I'm not sure, because in your example you use Vue 2 syntax.

If the data should be reactive, you can set up a simple state management as explained in the Vue documentation: [Simple state management](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html#simple-state-management-from-scratch).

If the data is more complex than that, the next step will be [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org).

Comment: The simple state management seems the best option, but i can't figure out how to implement it in a single file component, every example i found use plain js and not sfc; can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Following @Igor answer I looked after the simple state management and found the [ref()](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#creating-standalone-reactive-values-as-refs) method that creates reactive primitive values.

In my specific use case I needed to share among all the sfc instances just an array, so in my sfc I had:

```js
const reactive_array = ref([]);

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            shared_array: reactive_array,
        };
    },
};
```